# It would be considered cannibalism if a humanoid-lizard eats other humanoids?

Tags: ethics, humanoid, food

Even when they would be considered different species, a humanoid lizard from others humanoids, all the humanoid intelligent species are considered people with the same dignity and rights. So technically it shouldn't be considered cannibalism from a scientific point of view, but how societies judge people sometimes differ from science.

So, would it be considered cannibalism by other humanoid lizards if a comrade eats some other humanoids like elfs or orcs?

take in acount this:

1. It's not about if it is something good or bad, as it envolve killing it would be bad in the majority of cases, just if it would be considered cannibalism.
2. It doesn't matter the opinion of the other humanoids about it, obiusly the people being eaten are highly biased to have a relevant opion on the term that should be used.

Comment: Technically...no, it won't be cannibalism. But that isn't to say that these other races might be a little miffed that you thought Steve was delicious (even if he was already dead) and are now eyeing Bob.

Comment: What's a "person"?  If chips and gorillas become sentient, they still aren't **people**, because "people" are humans, and humans aren't chimps or gorillas.

Comment: Considering that many species of lizards are canibals, it might not be inconceivable that a species of intelligent lizards never developed a taboo of canibalism in the first place. So they might not even consider it inappropriate of one of them to eat one of their own kind. In general, you can not assume that any species would share the ethical values of us. As a world-builder it's up to you to set a moral value system for each species and culture you come up with.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: Probably**

Throughout humanities history, we have expressed a distaste in eating things closer to our own level of intelligence. To provide an example, we are less inclined to eat monkeys or dogs, compared to cows, which are lower down on the intelligence scale. Even though these acts would not scientifically be cannibalism, there is still societal stigma attached with the act. Following that vein, to eat something of comparable intelligence to us would most likely carry even more stigma associated with it. So even if it is not considered cannibalism in the scientific sense, societal judgment would still be present.

Comment: As long as there are plants (that aren't sentient) then eating other sentient creatures will considered improper. However, considering his other question, any orc would gladly eat a dwarf. Dwarf's Head Stew, mother's favorite dish.

Comment: One addition thought (damnable editing process anyway). If there is an existing tradition of everyone eating everyone else then there can be no conflict regarding doing so. If the eating is contained to eating those vanquished then eating randomly dead would lack honor. But, assuming eating others like yourself would be in poor taste. hehe. As is eating anyone you can have a conversation with.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can't be considered like cannibalism, you are eating other species (sentients, but not humans). By science it isn't cannibalism, and by society, I think the same, this should be considered like monstrosity or predation, but not cannibalism, I mean, this would be considered **very bad** but not cannibalism. However, humans eat fewer animals with similar intelligence or animals that use to have like a pet (dog, cat), so, again, this isn't cannibalism, but it's very controversial by the society.

Also, you should see [Cannibalism - does eating other sentient creatures make you a cannibal?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69044/cannibalism-does-eating-other-sentient-creatures-makes-you-a-cannibal?rq=1).

I hope this could help you.